# merge two or more node in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

There are 3 scenarios in this problem:

**First possibility:**
Input:

```
<root>
    <node id="N1">
        <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
            <orange id="x" action="create">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Orange</color>
                    <year>2012</year>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
            <orange id="x" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Red</color>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
            <orange id="x" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>
                    <condition>good</condition>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
        </fruit>
    </node>
</root>
```

Expected output:

```
<root>
    <node id="N1">
        <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
            <orange id="x" action="create">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>
                    <year>2012</year>
                    <condition>good</condition>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
        </fruit>
    </node>
</root>
```

**Second Possibility:** 
Input:

```
<root>
    <node id="N1">
        <car id="1">
            <bmw id="i" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>
                    <owner>a</owner>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
            <bmw id="i" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Yellow</color>
                    <status>avaailable</status>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
        </car>
    </node>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<root>
    <node id="N1">
        <car id="1">
            <bmw id="i" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Yellow</color>
                    <owner>a</owner>
                    <status>available</status>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
        </car>
    </node>
</root>
```

**Third Scenario:**

```
<root>
    <node id="N1">
        <car id="1">
            <bmw id="j" action="delete">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>
                    <year>2000</year>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
            <bmw id="j" action="delete">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Pink</color>
                    <status>available</status>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>
        </car>
    </node>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<root>
    <node id="N1">
        <car id="1">
            <bmw id="j" action="delete">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Pink</color>
                    <year>2000</year>
                    <status>available</status>
                </attribute>
            </bmw>            
        </car>
    </node>
</root>
```

Explanation on second and third scenario:

- Two or more node with 'action=change' will be merged into one node with 'action=change'
- Two or more node with 'action=delete' will be merged into one node with 'action=delete'
- while merging, we update we only keep the value from the last node, keep the initial node and add any new additional node with it.

I hope the explanation is clear.

Please advise me on XSLT solution for this problem. 
Thank you.

kind regards,
John

Comment: Not clear what are all "valid" sequences of "create", "change" and "delete". How can a sequence start with "delete" if there is no previous "create"? Does a "delete" delete the object, or does it only delete the contained attributes? Please, edit the question and explain. I have to guess about the semantics of repeated "change" actions and it seems to me that you still haven't given us a fully representative example. In the example only attributes contained in the last "change" should be merged with the initial attributes --guess intermediate "change" attributes also must be merged.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I have added more explanation I hope it clears now. That is the only possible scenario for the create, change and delete order. Thanks very much.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev hi, do you by any chance have a possible solution for the problem? Thank you.

Comment: When I understand the problem -- only then I can answer. The problems you are posting continue to be incompletely defined and there is no sense in spending time to solve such problems.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev hi, I have change the approach on explaining the problem. Do you mind have a look at it. I hope it is understandable now. Many thanks.

Comment: @John, this question has somewhat different flavor to building a superset of those attributes compared to this one you asked in parallel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419095/how-to-simplify-xml-node-between-sibling-to-make-sure-no-duplicate-node-exist-us. Are you satisfied with the solution I posted to that one or you need both flavors implemented?

Comment: @PavelVeller Yes, this one is different one. If you don't mind I would like to see the solution of this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution of a different flavor compared to the one I gave you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419095/how-to-simplify-xml-node-between-sibling-to-make-sure-no-duplicate-node-exist-us).

I figured it would be worth to go step by step. I made an assumption about `@action`s appearing in a logical order - `create` first, `change` next, and `remove` last. There can be multiple occurrences of the same `@action` but it wouldn't be random. Now we're ready to look at the main logic:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

We declare the identity transformation and then intercept it in a few places. We only stop at unique occurrences of a node with the same `@id`, parent `@id`, and `@action`:

```
<xsl:template match="node/*/*[a:is-primary(.)]" priority="1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute" mode="consolidate-most-recent"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

We ignore the "duplicates":

```
<xsl:template match="node/*/*[not(a:is-primary(.))]"/>
```

and also ignore `create`s following by a `change` as well as all `create`s and `change` followed by a `remove`.

```
<xsl:template match="node/*/*[@action = 'change'][a:preceded-by(., 'create')]" priority="2"/>
<xsl:template match="node/*/*[@action = 'create' or action='change'][a:followed-by(., 'remove')]" priority="2"/>
```

When the unique `@action` not followed by another `@action` that would make us ignore it is captured, we do a simple thing - collect all attributes of elements with the same `@id`s ignoring the `@action` and use their most "recent" values (the ones appearing last in the document order).

```
<xsl:template match="attribute" mode="consolidate-most-recent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group 
                    select="/root/node/*/*[a:matches(current()/parent::*, ., 'any')]/attribute/*" 
                    group-by="local-name()">
            <!-- take the last in the document order -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

That's it. Now let's look at the functions that would make it work:

We have got a `key` to simplify the lookup

```
<xsl:key name="entity" match="/root/node/*/*" use="concat(parent::*/@id, '_', @id, '_', @action)"/>
```

A function to check whether it's that unique occurrence of the node (we could add this directly into the template `match` predicate but since we started with the functions anyway let's just keep it the same):

```
<xsl:function name="a:is-primary" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="ctx"/>
    <!-- need to establish "focus"(context) for the key() function to work -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$ctx">
        <xsl:sequence select="generate-id($ctx) = generate-id(key('entity', concat($ctx/parent::*/@id, '_', $ctx/@id, '_', $ctx/@action))[1])"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>
```

a `matches` function that will do all kind of comparisons for us (again, can put it all in predicates but this way we'll keep it nice and clean in the real templates):

```
<xsl:function name="a:matches" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="src"/>
    <xsl:param name="target"/>
    <!-- can be one of the following:
        'any' - only match the @id(s) and ignore @action
        'same' - match by @id(s) and expect $src/@action to match $target/@action
         a certain value - match by @id(s) and expect @action to match this value
     -->
    <xsl:param name="action"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="
                  ($src/local-name() = $target/local-name()) and
                  ($src/parent::*/@id = $target/parent::*/@id) and 
                  ($src/@id = $target/@id) and 
                  (if ($action = 'any') 
                      then true()
                      else if ($action = 'same')
                          then ($target/@action = $src/@action)
                          else ($target/@action = $action))"/>  
</xsl:function>
```

And the `preceded-by` and `followed-by` syntax sugar on top of the "raw" `matches` function:

```
<xsl:function name="a:preceded-by" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="ctx"/>
    <xsl:param name="action"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="count($ctx/preceding::*[a:matches($ctx, ., $action)]) > 0"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="a:followed-by" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="ctx"/>
    <xsl:param name="action"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="count($ctx/following::*[a:matches($ctx, ., $action)]) > 0"/>
</xsl:function>
```

**SUMMARY**

Here's a full transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:a="http://a.com">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="entity" match="/root/node/*/*" use="concat(parent::*/@id, '_', @id, '_', @action)"/>

    <xsl:function name="a:is-primary" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="ctx"/>
        <!-- need to establish "focus"(context) for the key() function to work -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$ctx">
            <xsl:sequence select="generate-id($ctx) = generate-id(key('entity', concat($ctx/parent::*/@id, '_', $ctx/@id, '_', $ctx/@action))[1])"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:function> 

    <xsl:function name="a:preceded-by" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="ctx"/>
        <xsl:param name="action"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="count($ctx/preceding::*[a:matches($ctx, ., $action)]) > 0"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="a:followed-by" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="ctx"/>
        <xsl:param name="action"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="count($ctx/following::*[a:matches($ctx, ., $action)]) > 0"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="a:matches" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="src"/>
        <xsl:param name="target"/>
        <!-- can be one of the following:
            'any' - only match the @id(s) and ignore @action
            'same' - match by @id(s) and expect $src/@action to match $target/@action
             a certain value - match by @id(s) and expect @action to match this value
         -->
        <xsl:param name="action"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="
                      ($src/local-name() = $target/local-name()) and
                      ($src/parent::*/@id = $target/parent::*/@id) and 
                      ($src/@id = $target/@id) and 
                      (if ($action = 'any') 
                          then true()
                          else if ($action = 'same')
                              then ($target/@action = $src/@action)
                              else ($target/@action = $action))"/>  
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node/*/*[a:is-primary(.)]" priority="1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute" mode="consolidate-most-recent"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attribute" mode="consolidate-most-recent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group 
                        select="/root/node/*/*[a:matches(current()/parent::*, ., 'any')]/attribute/*" 
                        group-by="local-name()">
                <!-- take the last in the document order -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node/*/*[not(a:is-primary(.))]"/>

    <!-- assume a remove is never followed by a change or create -->
    <xsl:template match="node/*/*[@action = 'change'][a:preceded-by(., 'create')]" priority="2"/>
    <xsl:template match="node/*/*[@action = 'create' or action='change'][a:followed-by(., 'remove')]" priority="2"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to a document:

```
<root>
    <node id="N1">
        <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
            <orange id="x" action="create">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Orange</color>
                    <year>2012</year>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
            <orange id="x" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Red</color>
                    <something>!!</something>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
            <orange id="x" action="change">
                <attribute>
                    <color>Blue</color>
                    <condition>good</condition>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
            <orange id="x" action="remove">
                <attribute>
                    <condition>awesome</condition>
                </attribute>
            </orange>
        </fruit>
    </node>
</root>
```

produces the following result:

```
<root>
   <node id="N1">
      <fruit id="1" action="aaa">
         <orange id="x" action="remove">
            <attribute>
               <color>Blue</color>
               <year>2012</year>
               <something>!!</something>
               <condition>awesome</condition>
            </attribute>
         </orange>
      </fruit>
   </node>
</root>
```

I hope it's clear. You can expand on this concept and build yourself a nice library of those reusable functions that you would then use as simple predicates merging your nodes one way or the other. Unlikely to be the most effective way to do the job but at least a clean way to express the solution.

Comment: thank you for such an extensive explanation. Really appreciate it.